# Get RadioButtonList value from database & selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to populate My RadioButtonList values from database. That is working for me. But I am not getting how should I keep one predefined values in database to be selected by default in radiobuttonList. I have list of cities in my db table. One city I want to be selected when page loads. Following is my code

```
Private Sub MasterPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Me.PopulateCities()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateCities()
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "Select cityName from cities where status = 'active' order by cityName"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim item As New ListItem()
                        item.Text = sdr("cityName").ToString()
                        item.Value = sdr("cityName").ToString()
                        item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                        locationSelector.Items.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Of what type is column `IsSelected` in your DB? Additionally: You don´t select this column in your query.

Comment: You was only select `cityName` from table. change your query `Select cityName, IsSelected from cities where status = 'active' order by cityName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you database `cities` table contains `IsSelected` field then you need to change your query like this

```
Select cityName, IsSelected from cities where status = 'active' order by cityName
```

Elese you need to update your first list item

```
locationSelector.Items(0).Selected = True
```